# Fill a QScatterDataArray with a QVector from coordinates in a table

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to fill a [QScatterDataArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscatterdataproxy.html#QScatterDataArray-typedef) with some [QVector3D](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector3d.html), which themselves get their data from an array. I know how to do it manually, but I don't know how to do it automatically. I guess you'll have to use a for loop, though, I don't see how. I also want to say that I never use QT, so the answer might seem obvious to you.

Here is the code I would like to modify:

```
// "graph" is therefore my graph

QScatter3DSeries *series = new QScatter3DSeries(graph);
QScatterDataArray data;

data << QVector3D(50, 10, 0) << QVector3D(5, 8, 9) << QVector3D(0, 10, 15)
<< QVector3D(30, 50, 02) << QVector3D(15, 83, 7) << QVector3D(04, 20, 45)
<< QVector3D(40, 014, 10) << QVector3D(35, 28, 21) << QVector3D(04, 0, 15)
<< QVector3D(70, 10, 27) << QVector3D(15, 28, 47) << QVector3D(062, 70, 45)
<< QVector3D(50, 10, 0) << QVector3D(5, 8, 17) << QVector3D(031, 20, 35);

series->dataProxy()->addItems(data);
graph->addSeries(series);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: what would be bad about loop of adding vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `QScatterDataArray` is a [typedef](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscatterdataproxy.html#QScatterDataArray-typedef) for a vector of `QScatterDataItems`.

`QScatterDataItem` has a [constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscatterdataitem.html#QScatterDataItem-1) taking a `QVector3D`.

So iterate the table of coordinates, constructing a `QVector3D` for each one and `push_back` onto `data`.

One way, not the only way, of doing that would be:

```
QScatterDataArray data;

for ( /* each xyz coordinate in some table */ )
{
    data.push_back(QScatterDataItem(QVector3d(x, y, z)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
This does not differ much from a classical vector in fact.